# Can't change a state a value/use a result of a function inside another function -getting undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

Getting undefined value of handleClick() in countStat(). What is the exact problem happening right there? What should I change in the code?

```
class Widget extends Component {
  state = {
    good: 0,
    neutral: 0,
    bad: 0
  };

  handleClick(event) {
    const id = event.target.id;
    return id;
  }

  countStat(id, e) {
    id = this.handleClick(e);
    if (id === "good") {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        good: prevState.good + 1
      }));
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <li className={classes.Button}>
        <button onClick={this.countStat} id="good">
          Good
        </button>
      </li>
    );
  }
}

export default Widget;
```

Comment: Change the signature of your `countStat(id, e)` function to `countStat(e)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple issues

1. `this` isn't bound to `countStat` nor `handleClick`
2. `countStat` function signature doesn't match usage

## Solution

1. Bind this to `countStat` in a constructor, or use an arrow function, and remove `handleClick` since it isn't used/necessary
2. Update `countStat` function to get `id` from `event.target`

Updated component

```
class Widget extends Component {
  state = {
    good: 0,
    neutral: 0,
    bad: 0
  };

  countStat = e => {
    const { id } = e.target;
    if (id === "good") {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        good: prevState.good + 1
      }));
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <li className={classes.Button}>
        <button onClick={this.countStat} id="good">
          Good
        </button>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! but i still don't understand why this isn't bound to countStat nor handleClick...

Comment: @ElMuchacho Maybe this explain? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable TL;DR though is that functions don't inherit the `this` of the caller, the class component in this case, so they have to be manually bound to `this` of the component. Arrow function notation does this for you.

Answer (score 3):

To make it work you can do:

```
<button onClick={(event) => this.countStat('good', event)} id="good">Good</button>
```